# Swing GUI design

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, jcomponent

I am newbie in Swing GUI components. I have to design a component like the image below.

[image]

I didn't know exactly what kind of gui component I have to use for this.
I am looking for suitable component like "Master & Details" panels in the image.

Panel should get the border and get the header section. In the header section I want to be place the panel name in the left as it is in the image & I want to place some labels in right side corner on this header. Please suggest me the suitable component.

Comment: I don't quite get what the two upper components (Master/Detail) are.  Are they (entries in) lists?  The bottom one would be a `JSlider`  For a layout, probably `BorderLayout`.

Comment: *"Panel should get the border and get the header section"*  Is **that** what you mean by the `Master`/`Detail` ..labels?  I'm very confused.  If that is so, perhaps a `TitledBorder` around a standard `JPanel` would produce something like it.  See also [A Visual Guide to Swing Components](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/ui/features/components.html) for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
JPanel demoPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,10));
demoPanel.add(new JLabel("Demo"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
JPanel master = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
master.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));
master.add(new JLabel("Master"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

JPanel detail = new JPanel();
detail.add(new JLabel("Detail"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
detail.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED));

JPanel alpha = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
alpha.add(new JLabel("Alpha (translucency)"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL);
slider.setMaximum(100);
slider.setMinimum(0);
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
alpha.add(slider, BorderLayout.CENTER);

demoPanel.add(master, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
demoPanel.add(detail, BorderLayout.CENTER);
demoPanel.add(alpha, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

It doesn't have the exact UI design (with the colors and spacing between the component) as your screenshot, but it gives you basic layout and should get you started